# React.useEffect dependency has a missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-typescript

I want to use the checked value in useEffect but don't want to add it in dependency
array as I don't want useEffect to be called on checked updation.

But I am getting the warning **"React Hook useEffect has missing dependency :"checked".Either include it or remove the dependency array".**

```
const[checked , setChecked] = React.useState(false);

useEffect(() = >{
     if(data.length && !checked){
        setChecked(true)
     }
     else{
      //something
     }
    },[data]);
```

Comment: @LucaPizzini, as I have mentioned I don't useEffect to be called on updating the checked value so adding checked in dependency array will call the useEffect as soon as it gets updated.

Comment: What causes data to be updated? Could you describe more about what the component is doing (and maybe share the component code)? If you don't want to include checked in the dependency array, then maybe there's a better way to refactor your code to not even need this in the first place.

Comment: If the code works and does what you want it to, you can disable the warning with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is with a [usePrevious](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/) hook to track the last value of `checked`. If `prevChecked` and `checked` are not equal, then you would cancel early.

```js
const[checked , setChecked] = React.useState(false);

const prevChecked = usePrevious(checked)

useEffect(() = >{
  if (prevChecked !== checked) return
  
  if(data.length && !checked){
    setChecked(true)
  }
  else{
  //something
  }
},[data, prevChecked, checked]);
```